# Terraform - Append an entity ID to Vault Identity Group

Tags: list, append, terraform, hashicorp-vault, hcl

I have the following internal vault identity group set up on a file named "groups.tf":

```
resource "vault_identity_group" "group_a" {
    member_entity_ids =  ["<ID_1>"]
    type = "internal"
}
```

I created a script that fetches a different ID, "<ID_2>", and I'd like to append it to the existing group configuration on Terraform.

Does anyone know how can I edit "groups.tf" in order to append the ID to the list? End goal will look like this:

```
resource "vault_identity_group" "group_a" {
    member_entity_ids =  ["<ID_1>","<ID_2>"]
    type = "internal"
}
```

I've tried using tools such as python-hcl, but sadly I can only parse existing configuration, and manipulate it, but not export it to a .tf file.

Thanks!

Comment: "I created a script" what script? What's wrong with it? Its not shown in your question.

Comment: @Marcin The script is not related to the issue. The script retrieves <ID_2> via curl. And I'd like to append the retrieved string to the .tf configuration.

Comment: Why not retrieve the ID with `data` in the TF provider instead of an independent invocation against Vault's API? Is there some reason this could not all be managed in the TF config?

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thanks for your answer, Matt. We provision a set amount of vault identity groups per supported product. The easiest way to provision them is through TF. The only issue with the internal groups is the member_entity_ids field has to be micromanaged. When a new entity is provisioned, I'd like his ID to immediately be associated with a certain group, which has been provisioned by Terraform.

Comment: Based on your comment, it then does sound like you could leverage https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vault/latest/docs/data-sources/identity_entity instead of the independent script.